# How to include a file located outside of the test folder when testing a Julia Package

Tags: julia

I am trying to do a few tests on my package and the file I need to use is located in the data folder so when I try to use it in my code I do `randomFuncName(joinpath(@__DIR__, "src", "data", "etc", "etc"))` but the issue is that since I am in the "test" folder (given that I am running the tests) it creates the relative path of ".../.../test/src/data/..." instead of just "src/data".

Any ideas on how I can specify this path without using the absolute path (such that it works on CI and other systems)?

Comment: Csn you specify the wanted path as relative to your test directory? Eg ../data?

Comment: Maybe dirname(@__DIR__) to get the parent?

Comment: The test, src, and data folder are all in the root. So I would technically have to switch directories to get to the data folder or sec folder since they are at the same level as the test folder.

Comment: `@__DIR__` is depends on the file you're in, not `pwd`. So you could call `f(joinpath(@__DIR__, "foo.jl"))` from inside of `src` and `f(joinpath(@__DIR__, "..", "src", "foo.jl"))` from inside `test`.

Comment: @pfitzseb this worked! Can you switch this to be the answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`@__DIR__` depends on the file you're in, not `pwd`. So you could call `f(joinpath(@__DIR__, "foo.jl"))` from inside of `src` and `f(joinpath(@__DIR__, "..", "src", "foo.jl"))` from inside `test`.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer using the location of the package rather than relying on relative paths.
For example when you project grows you might want to have many test files and move them around to subfolders. Relying on `joinpath(@__DIR__, "..","something")` always means that you are making some assumptions on where your file running tests is located.

Hence what I would do is to use `pathof(Module)`:

```
using PackageName
BASE_FOLDER = dirname(dirname(pathof(PackageName)))
test_file = joinpath(BASE_FOLDER, "data", "file.txt")
```

Of course this is very subjective :-)